# Вопрос по сессиям php

Tags: php, сессия

есть такая функция как session_start();
и если мне надо чтобы сессия длилась в течении перехода по нескольким страницам сайта надо ли эту функцию обьявлять на каждой странице где она нужна или только на первой?

Comment: да, надо на каждой странице.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, эту функцию следует объявлять на каждой странице, где она нужна (если Вы собираетесь пользоваться сессией) **до** вывода чего-либо на экран!